# How to perform two different actions in merge when "not matched"

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I have these two tables

```
TABLE1
nrb   score  note  source
nrb1    500  abc   e1
nrb2    500  def   e1
```

and

```
TABLE2
nrb   score  note  source
nrb1    500  gls   e1
nrb3    500  dls   e1
```

There are three cases in which I want to perform different actions. I need to modify Table1 with new values:

1. WHEN MATCHED (by NRB) (f.ex. "nrb1") I want to keep values from `table1` to this `nrb`, so basicly: do nothing with this record
2. WHEN NOT MATCHED #1: there is `nrb` in `table2` but not in `table1` (e.g. `'nrb3'`) I want to insert the values for this `nrb` from `table2` to `table1`
3. WHEN NOT MATCHED #2: if there is `nrb` in `table1` but not in `table2` (e.g `'nrb2'`) I want to change `score` in `table1` from 500 to 5

So in the end it should look like this:

```
TABLE1
nrb   score  note  source
nrb1    500  abc   e1 [stays the same]
nrb2      5  def   e1 [score changed]
nrb3    500  dls   e1 [new record from table2]
```

I need to use Oracle's `merge` statement for this task but I don't know how to perform two different actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do two separate tasks using two different **SQL**. Because **MERGE** doesn't support **UPDATE** clause for **WHEN NOT MATCHED** condition.

- **MERGE INSERT**
- **UPDATE WHERE  NOT EXISTS**

**Setup**:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t1(
  2  nrb VARCHAR2(10), score NUMBER, note VARCHAR2(10), SOURCE VARCHAR2(10)
  3  );

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES('nrb1', 500, 'abc', 'e1');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES('nrb2', 500, 'def', 'e1');

1 row created.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL> CREATE TABLE t2(
  2  nrb VARCHAR2(10), score NUMBER, note VARCHAR2(10), SOURCE VARCHAR2(10)
  3  );

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t2 VALUES('nrb1', 500, 'gls', 'e1');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t2 VALUES('nrb3', 500, 'dls', 'e1');

1 row created.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.
```

**MERGE INSERT**: To insert unmatched rows

```
SQL> MERGE INTO t1
  2  USING t2
  3  ON (t1.nrb = t2.nrb)
  4  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  5    INSERT
  6      (
  7        nrb,
  8        score,
  9        note,
 10        SOURCE
 11      )
 12      VALUES
 13      (
 14        t2.nrb,
 15        t2.score,
 16        t2.note,
 17        t2.SOURCE
 18      );

1 row merged.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL> SELECT * FROM t1;

NRB             SCORE NOTE       SOURCE
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
nrb1              500 abc        e1
nrb2              500 def        e1
nrb3              500 dls        e1
```

**UPDATE** statement: To update the non-matched rows with custom value

```
SQL> UPDATE t1
  2  SET    score = 5
  3  WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
  4                     FROM   t2
  5                     WHERE  t1.nrb = t2.nrb);

1 row updated.

SQL>                    COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL> SELECT * FROM t1;

NRB             SCORE NOTE       SOURCE
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
nrb1              500 abc        e1
nrb2                5 def        e1
nrb3              500 dls        e1
```

**NOTE** Instead of **MERGE** with only INSERT, you could simply write a single **INSERT** statement. Although, from `10g` on wards, the The MATCHED and NOT MATCHED clauses are optional, so you could have single INSERT or single UPDATE statements.

Comment: It's worth noting this will set set all non matching values to 5. Depending on your dataset and the rules around scores of non-500 (e.g. what if the score is 502? 6000? etc.) then you will need to add this to the where clause also if needed.

Comment: works perfectly, thank you very much. got a question considering your update statement, why would your "where not exist" be more optimal than simple "not in (select" ? like this:
    update tab1 
    set score = 5
    where nrb not in (select nrb from tab2);

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:953229842074 This is a better response than the one previously linked.

Comment: @bobdylan Here the focus was mpre on the logic of MERGE and non mapping rows, OP should be able to understand the scope and other aspects of it or ask for further clarification. The solution is in the scope of whatever OP has posted in the question :-)

Comment: @ŁukaszStasiak There is a huge difference between NOT EXISTS and NOT IN. It is a FAQ, search for the difference in Google, probably Tom Kyte has answered it beautifully in AskTom.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that in a single merge. The `when not matched` clause can *only* insert, not update, as [the syntax diagram](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9016.htm) shows.

[image]

Similarly the `when matched` clause can *only* update, not insert. You can't mix and match between them.

You will have to have a separate update statement. You can either merge to do the first part:

```
merge into table1 t1
using (select * from table2) t2
on (t2.nrb = t1.nrb)
when not matched then insert (nrb, score, note, source)
  values (t2.nrb, t2.score, t2.note, t2.source);
```

or do the equivalent insert:

```
insert into table1 (nrb, score, note, source)
select t2.nrb, t2.score, t2.note, t2.source
from table2 t2
where not exists (
  select null
  from table1 t1
  where t1.nrb = t2.nrb
);

select * from table1;

NRB       SCORE NOT SO
---- ---------- --- --
nrb1        500 abc e1
nrb2        500 def e1
nrb3        500 dls e1
```

And then whichever of those you do, update where there is no match:

```
update table1 t1
set score = score/100 -- or fixed value 5; unclear which you need
where not exists (
  select null
  from table2 t2
  where t2.nrb = t1.nrb
);

select * from table1;

NRB       SCORE NOT SO
---- ---------- --- --
nrb1        500 abc e1
nrb2          5 def e1
nrb3        500 dls e1
```

If you *really* wanted to to you could do that update via a merge, but it makes the `using` clause more complicated - the subset of `table1` that has no matcing record in `table2` - so I don't see any benefit:

```
merge into table1 t1
using (
  select * from table1 t1
  where not exists (
    select null from table2 t2 where t2.nrb = t1.nrb)) t2
on (t2.nrb = t1.nrb)
when matched then update set t1.score = score/100;
```